# Chown for every created file in folder

Tags: debian, chown

is there any way to achieve that every created file inside student's directory will have owner student (chown student ./* is for all old files, but I want new files to be chown student)....
By the way I have a Perl and Python on this Server so if there can be some simple script that will check the creating of the file and changes it's owner hmm?

Comment: you can set a default primary group with `chmod g+s directoryName` and use POSIX ACL's to give certain users and groups given amounts of access on files/directories within a given directory. If you need to coerce the file owner for some reason (discretionary access controls or quotas probably) then you're probably stuck running a `find` command in a cronjob or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
find /folder -not -uid 1050 -exec chown student:studentgroup {} +
```

means that `student` have user ID `1050`. To get the `uid` you can use command

```
id -u username
```

Comment: Use `-user student` instead of `-uid 1050`.

Comment: How to undo this command? i just screw up the access to that folder, noone can access it from remote PC...

Comment: You could change access to the folder using `chown user:group foldername`. It will not change the owners of the files into, but restore the owner and group of the folder.

Comment: ok so I know what's the problem. the problem is that the folder can have either owner teacher or student... It can be either accessed by the teacher or student... is it possible to make it to be accessed by both the teacher and the student?

Comment: You could set permission to read and write for: owner, group of owner and other users, to set read and write permission for everyone user use `chmod a+rw foldername`.  But **every** user could read and write this folder.

Comment: and how to make this automatically added into every created file in this folder? like this? find /folder -not -uid 1050 -exec chmod a+rw foldername {} +

Comment: You better open a question with "teachers and students need to access the same folder". It needs creating new group and adding teachers and students there, then setting the folder group owner to this group.